# check if regex contains a capturing group

Tags: php, regex, regex-group, capturing-group

I working on a routing system and i want to allow custom regex patterns.
My question is how can i detect if a regex contains a capturing group?

So for example the pattern `[0-9]+` would work, because it doesnt contain a capturing group. The pattern `([0-9]+)` would not work.

It tried to `ltrim` and `rtrim` the pattern by the `(` and `)` character mask, this would work with patterns that start with a capturing group like `([A-Za-z]+)` and `([0-9]+)`. But with patterns that contain a capturing group elsewhere this would not work. So how could i check if the pattern contains a capturing group?

Comment: Why won't you allow the user to use capturing groups? He can potentially use them to reference previous match. For example `([ab])c\1` will match `aca` or `bcb` but not `acb` or `bca`

Comment: and what is your target language?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, php

Answer (score 2):

First you should match and omit any escaped characters from results then check if there is any opening bracket remained alone or is followed by `?P<`, `?'` or `?<`. These are  opening syntax of a named capturing group.

```
\\.(*SKIP)(?!)|\((?(?=\?)\?(P?['<]\w+['>]))
```

PHP:

```
if (preg_match("~\\\\.(*SKIP)(?!)|\((?(?=\?)\?(P?['<]\w+['>]))~", $regex)) {
    // Capturing group found
}
```

RegEx Explanation:

```
\\.                     # Match any escaped character
(*SKIP)(?!)             # Skip over and omit recent match
|                       # OR
\(                      # Match a single `(`
(?(?=\?)                # Which if is followed by `?`
    \?                      #
    P?['<]\w+['>]           # Next characters should be matched as ?P'name', ?<name> or ?'name'
)                       # End of conditional statement
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to see if there are capturing groups e.g. `(something)` that are not at the start of the test pattern. This seems to work for me...

```
$pattern = '/^.+\(([^\)]+)\)/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $testpattern)) {
    // Capturing group found that is not at the start of the string
}
```